# Which geometric operations are encoded by symmetric, positive definite matrices?

Tags: matrices

Maybe it's because I'm German and used different terminology in the past, but somehow I don't really understand what is meant by the question in the title.
Didn't change the wording, just copied it.
Does anyone have any idea what the answer to the question could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some context?

Comment: Not really. It's just a follow-up question to identifying some transformation matrices (rotation, projection, etc.). It seems out of context to me as well, maybe that's why I don't quite get it.

Answer (score 1):

Projection matrices are always positive semi-definite (they need not be positive definite, but they could be). That is the only common geometric operation that I can think of being encoded by positive definite/semidefinite matrices.

In general, positive definite matrices give rise to convex quadratic forms, but I don't think that can be considered as a geometric 'operation'.

Comment: This really helped me. Turned out the question should basically read "Which of the geometric operations mentioned in exercise a)...", so there indeed was some context. But the thing about projection matrices helped me anyway, so thanks!